# SSH - PasswordAuthentication no has no effect

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sshd

I'm trying to configure my server to disable password authentication, I'm using keys now.

The problem is that `PasswordAuthentication no` is set, but it has had no effect. I'm still prompted for a password even though that's set.

More details:

- I'm connecting to Ubuntu Server 14.04 from PuTTY on Windows 10.
- `ssh -v` shows uses my key first then keyboard-interactive second.
- I made sure I edited `sshd_config`, not `ssh_config`.
- I restarted the `ssh` after applying the changes, when that had no effect I restarted the whole server, still no effect.
- I have this *exact same config file* on another 14.04 server with this *exact same key*, but it has no issues and password auth is disabled there.

Why isn't password auth disabled as it should be, and how can I fix it?

This is the entire `sshd_config` file minus all commented lines for brevity.

```
Port 612
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key

KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160,umac-128@openssh.com

UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no

PermitEmptyPasswords no

PasswordAuthentication no

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

UsePAM yes
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The thing is, that the password authentication using `PAM` (as on all the modern systems) is handled by `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` option, which is `yes` by default.

> **ChallengeResponseAuthentication**
>
> Specifies whether challenge-response authentication is allowed (e.g. via PAM).  The default is “yes”.

This is mentioned many times in the example `sshd_config`.

```
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
```

Add it to your `sshd_config` with value `no`, restart and it will work for you:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

Comment: That did it! I tried asking on the Ubuntu forums, no one knew what was up with it. Thank you!

Comment: In Ubuntu 23.04 `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` is called `KbdInteractiveAuthentication`

Comment: @Darkitechtor feel free to propose and edit. I no longer follow all the changes in openssh nor in here, but I can certainly review your proposal.

Comment: I've realized that there's also another configuration file included in the `sshd_config` file and that file has a similar rule that is taking precedence. In my case, the exact `Include` line at the top of the `sshd_config` file was: `Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf`, so I just head to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-cloud-init.conf` and fixed things there and now it is resolved.

Comment: Correct. The include solves a lot of issues (and creates new ones). But at the time of writing this answer, the Include was not implemented for server configuration.

Answer (score 2):

One silly mistake I made (and spent a while to realize) was that instead of editing `sshd_config` I was editing `ssh_config` and that was the reason why the changes did not have the intended effect.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on linux distributions, If you are using Ubuntu 22, try this:

```
sshd -T | grep passwordauthentication
```

if you see output `passwordauthentication yes`, some configurations are set prior to default /etc/ssh/sshd_config, they are located in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/` , you can search `passwordauthentication` from them or simply remove them by

```
rm /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of the changes in `sshd_config` were taking effect on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server on a Raspberry Pi 4. Purging `openssh-server` and reinstalling it solved it for me.

Commands for reference:

```
apt purge openssh-server
rm -rf /etc/ssh (may be necessary if using apt remove)
apt install openssh-server
```